# How to remove last few characters from each row/column from pandas (python) dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with lots of variation in format like this.

```
    -0.002672945<120>
    -0.077635566{600}
    5.88365537e-005{500}
   -0.116441565{1}
   -4.549649974<29.448>
```

There are all kinds of variety in the end of the values, I need to remove all those weird brackets, problem is sometimes they are 3 characters, some times 6, etc. I also cannot just take first few characters as there are scientific notation numbers such as 8.645637e-007 like this.

Is there a smart way to clear this kind of mess from data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [
... "-0.002672945<120>",
... "-0.077635566{600}",
... "5.88365537e-005{500}",
... "-0.116441565{1}",
... "-4.549649974<29.448>",
... ]})
>>> df["x"].replace(r"[<{].+$", "", regex=True)
0       -0.002672945
1       -0.077635566
2    5.88365537e-005
3       -0.116441565
4       -4.549649974
Name: x, dtype: object
>>>
```

You can assign that result back into the `df` then.

Comment: Thanks it works. can you explain the regex syntax, I see it can replace the brackets etc with '' (null) but how does it get rid of number in between as well. ?

Comment: Because it gets rid of everything (`.+`) after `<` or `{` until the end of string (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

The `str.split` function accepts regex too -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Carrot<x2>', 'Carrot{78}', 'Carrot<91'], 'Person': list('ABCDE')})

df.loc[:, 'Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].str.split(r'<|{', n=1, expand=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to clean those:

```py
df[column].str.replace(r'[<\[{].+?[>\]}]$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0       -0.002672945
1       -0.077635566
2    5.88365537e-005
3       -0.116441565
4       -4.549649974
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Breakdown of the regex:

```
[<\[{]  -- Character class; Matches ONE of ANY of the characters between the `[` and `]` (the `\[` is just a literal `[`, escaped)
.+?     -- "." means one of ANY character (except newline), "+" means one or more of the preceding token, ? means not to match the next thing...
[>\]}]  -- Character class
$       -- Only match this stuff if it occurs at the VERY END of the string
```